# How to use cropit in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Am unable to use cropit in my angular project. Can someone please help me resolve this issue? [Here](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/) is the link to my project.

Thnaks very much.

angular.module('cimm2cropit', []);

(function() {
    'use strict';

```
function cimm2cropit() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var gm = element.cropit({ 

            })
        },
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    }
}
cimm2cropit.$inject = [];

angular.module('cimm2cropit').directive('cimm2cropit', cimm2cropit);
```

})();

Comment: unable in the sense where ur facing the issue??

Comment: Since it is an jquery plugin. I need to use it in angular as directive.